# Compare only .f and .f90 files (~10 MB) in 2 huge (~1GB) directory trees with WINMERGE

Tags: winmerge

I have 2 directory trees (many subdirectories, up to 5-6 levels)  each having files  for a total of 1GB. I need to compare only the .f and .f90 text files inside this tree, that are only a small percentage (they occupy slightly less than 10 MB). Then I would like to have a list of .f and .f90 files in the result window, not a directory tree. In this way I can see immediately which are the different files and copy differences without having to browse through the directories. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -f flag on the command line to specify a file mask.

[Official link](http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html)

> In this command-line example, the folder compare operation includes only files with xml or txt extensions. All other files are omitted:

```
WinMergeU c:\project\docs c:\temp /f *.xml;*.txt
```